# Can I simply my lengthy shorthand string comparison?

Tags: c#

In one of my applications I receive a datastruct built like this:

> parent:
>   {
>     x,
>     y,
>     z,
>     child[]:
>      {
>       x,
>       y
>      }
>   }

I select the parent object, and then loop through all of the child objects. I use this data to create a 3rd object.

As you can see, some of the properties of the parent object can also be found in the child object. The parent object always has priority, so whenever I loop through the child objects I need to check whether or not I have a value @ the parent level for properties x & y. If I do, then I use the parent's value, if not it's the child's values that are being used.

Originally I created separate methods to these checks for me. I had one for int's, booleans and strings.

In the pull request I was asked to remove those methods and use the ? operator for my comparisons. I personally found my original way of working more readable, but OK.

Now, for the string comparisons I found that the expression to be used was somewhat lengthy:

```
B = parent.X != null ? (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent.X.XName) ? parent.X.XName
                                                              : child.X != null ? (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(child.X.XName) ? child.X.XName
                                                                                                                        : string.Empty)
                                                                                : string.Empty)
                     : (child.X != null ? !string.IsNullOrEmpty(child.X.XName) ? child.X.XName
                                                                               : string.Empty;
```

I'm wondering if there are ways to simplify it?

Comment: It seems like this is the wrong forum for this question, I suggest you try posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If there's a better way I'd run it past resharper

Comment: This code doesn't even look complete to me. Either way it's far too broad for Stack Overflow. Like MindSwipe suggests, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) might be a better option.

Comment: ...it also check child.X twice ...

Comment: Well, it's the code for 1 property and it does the trick. I just think it's lengthy, it's one of  3 or 4 statements like this.

Comment: with Elvis op: `B = parent?.X?.XName ?? child?.X?.XName ?? string.Empty;`

Comment: It needs to check Child.X twice since I can't use child.X if it doesn't have a value... then I have to use an "".

Comment: B = parent?.X?.XName ?? child?.X?.XName ?? child?.X?.XName ?? string.Empty;  Does it takes an empty string into account? I originally used this, but then my unit tests failed.

Comment: @Selvin if `parent.X.XName` is empty but `child.X.XName` isn't, your code won't produce expected output

Comment: no, it doesn't take empty string into account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var B = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent.X?.XName)
       ? parent.X.XName // parent.X is not null and parent.X.XName is neither null nor empty
       : (child.X?.XName ?? string.Empty);
```

This should produce expected output.

i.e:

- `parent.X.XName` if `parent.X` is not `null` and `parent.X.XName` is not `null` or empty
- `child.X.XName` if above is false and `child.X` and `child.X.XName` are not `null`
- `string.Empty` if above is false

---

It would be the same as:

```
var B = parent.X != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent.X.XName)
    ? parent.X.XName
    : child.X != null && child.X.XName != null
        ? child.X.XName
        : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thank you. :-) But the problem is I can't return a null, I need to return an empty string. :-)

Comment: @Fysicus I explained only a part of the statement. The full statement does not return `null`. Please check my edit

Comment: And it works. Thx.